# Which devices supports TelephonyManager getNeighboringCellInfo()

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to use the getNeighboringCellInfo() function of the TelephonyManager.
But all devices i own doesn't support it.

Is there anywhere a list of supported devices?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a complete list (if there is one, I'd surely like to know), but have some reports of devices:

- Nexus S: Not supported (tested)
- Galaxy Nexus: Not supported (tested)
- Nexus 4: Not known but `getAllCellInfo()` is supported ([source](https://github.com/mozilla/MozStumbler/issues/72))
- Nexus 5: Supported ([source](https://github.com/mozilla/MozStumbler/issues/72))
- Most (if not all) Samsung devices: Not supported (reportedly)
- OnePlus One: Supported (tested)

Since the Nexus 5 is built by LG, you might also be lucky with other LG devices (at least if they are of the same generation and thus likely to share components with the Nexus 5). The Oppo N1 might share some components with the OnePlus One and thus support it as well.